# Bower: invalid option: --allow-root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, bower, bower-install

I'm having this issue on ubuntu 14.04LTS:

When I do `rake bower:install:dev` I get:

> Error: EACCES, permission denied
>   'home/MyName/.config/configstore/bower-github.yml' You don't have access to this
>   file.

When I do `sudo rake bower:install:dev` I get:

> bower ESUDO         Cannot be run with sudo
>
> Additional error details: Since bower is a user command, there is no
>   need to execute it with superuser permissions. If you're having
>   permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few
>   minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any
>   necessary repairs.
>
> http://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm
>   https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814
>
> You can however run a command with sudo using --allow-root option

When I do `sudo rake bower:install:dev --allow-root` I get:

> invalid option: --allow-root

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: what's the output of `ll bower-github.yml` command ?

Comment: bower-github.yml doesn't exist in inside the ruby application folder. The output of the command is: ls: cannot access bower-github.yml: No such file or directory

Comment: I meant this file `home/MyName/.config/configstore/bower-github.yml` file it doesn't exists ?

Comment: It does exist, but I already solved the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by adding .bowerrc file in the root of my app with the following content:

```
{ "allow_root": true }
```